# Get the name of functions on errors

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling, eval

I have a program which compiles js from ajax requests with the new Function(), and I am trying to know from which file the error originated, I have tried to

```
var f = new Function(code);
Object.defineProperty(f, "name", {writable:true});
f.name = 'myFuncName';
```

But still when an error happens it shows anonymos:2:3

I have also tried to do this

```
try {
  var f = new Function(code);
}catch(e){
  console.log(e)
}
```

But the error doesn't get catched, I think is because the code inside the function is async

Any ideas?

Comment: `because the code inside the function is async` Sounds like you should give that *inner* function a `name`, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

you can try with

```
var f = function myFuncName (){
    return (new Function(code))
        .apply(this, arguments)
};
```

Comment: This does work, but is there a way to make myFuncName dynamic?